# What is the idiomatic way to express countable infinity in Coq?

Tags: coq

Suppose I wish to assert that a countably infinite number of distinct `x : X`'s exist. My first guess is to follow the definition of countable infinity literally, such as :

```
Definition aleph_null ( X : Type ) :=
exists ( R : nat -> X -> Prop ), 
( forall ( n : nat ), exists ( x : X ), R n x )
/\ ( forall ( x : X ), exists ( n : nat ), R n x )
/\ ( forall ( n : nat ) ( x y : X ), R n x -> R n y -> x = y )
/\ ( forall ( n m : nat ) ( x : X ), R n x -> R m x -> n = m ).
```

But it seems a bit unwieldy to use in actual proofs, and doesn't make use of libraries.
I thought I could make it shorter by using an existing definition of bijectivity, but all definitions I can find are about functions, not binary relations.

Is there a better, idiomatic way to express countable infinity in Coq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best choice would very much depend on the particular application you have in mind. I would say that using functions is probably the easiest alternative for most cases. Since you mentioned library support, the [ssreflect](http://ssr.msr-inria.inria.fr/) library has very good support for this kind of reasoning; you can define, for instance

```
Inductive count_inf (X : Type) : Type := CountInf {
  count : X -> nat;
  _ : bijective count
}.
```

ssreflect actually comes with its own definition of [countable types](http://ssr.msr-inria.inria.fr/~jenkins/current/choice.html), but it includes both finite and infinite types, so it doesn't give you want you want out of the box.